Wacom Intuos 4 PTK 440 on MacBook Pro on macOS Sonoma
I have an Wacom Intuos 4 tablet that works perfectly, and I would like to use it on my brand new MBP running macOS 14.4.1 Sonoma.
I  installed the latest version of the Wacom Center and driver (macOS Driver 6.4.6-1), as well as the driver intended for the Intuos 4  (driver v6.3.41-2) which is compatible with macOS 11.
Is there a workaround to make it function on macOS 14?
It would be a shame to discard products that still perform very well...

Unfortunately, Wacom has discontinued support for the Intuos 4 PTK 440 on Sonoma. Here is the list of EOL products:


This sounds more like getting the physical item repaired as opposed to having the software to run on macOS Sonoma as asked by the OP.

It says "or support services".

Over time, manufacturers will stop supporting older hardware with newer software. I had his happen with an Intuos 3 and was able to find a "modified" driver for it by thenickdude on GitHub.
There is an issue on the GitHub repository about using the "modified" driver with an Intuos 4. thenickdude's response was:

My 6.3.15-3 driver incidentally fully supports Intuos 4, since support for Intuos 4 tablets was first added in Wacom driver version 6.1.6-4.

This could be the best solution for your situation.
